# cephfs seems to have a problem with linux 5.11 kernels

Tags: ceph, cephfs

Upgraded fedora33 lately and found my cephfs mounts won't work anymore. After hours of debugging and looking around, I realized a new kernel 5.11.X was installed. Before I had 5.10.X. Did reboot with 5.10 and everything was fine. To verify the kernel version is the problem I installed a recent ubuntu 21.04 with kernel 5.11.0: showed the same problem. Now I have fixed my kernel to boot to 5.10 and I can live with that, but there seems to be a serious problem with > 5.10 kernels.
I'm using octopus. Any ideas?

Adding ms_mode=legacy does not help.

When I try to mount I get lot's of kernel logs starting with:

```
    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: libceph: no match of type 2 in addrvec
    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: libceph: corrupt full osdmap (-2) epoch 64001 off 3154 (0000000073edcb82 of 00000000aaa67e88-00000000ea93de62)
    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: osdmap: 00000000: 08 07 72 20 00 00 09 01 9e 12 00 00 86 bb d6 c5  ..r ............
    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: osdmap: 00000010: ae 96 4c 78 8a 5e 50 62 3f 0a e5 24 01 fa 00 00  ..Lx.^Pb?..$....
    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: osdmap: 00000020: 54 f0 53 5d 3a fd ae 0e 3e ea 85 60 07 ab 94 2b  T.S]:...>..`...+
    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: osdmap: 00000030: 06 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1d 05 44 01  ..............D.
    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: osdmap: 00000040: 00 00 01 02 02 02 20 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00  ...... ... .....
    .....

    Apr 26 09:22:15 ubuntu kernel: libceph: osdc handle_map corrupt msg
    ....
```

Magnus

Comment: I would recommend to write to the ceph-users [mailing-list](https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/), I'm sure someone there will have an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this. I'm booting my linux with 5.10.X and it works well but when I switch to the 5.11.X I have the corrupt message and cannot attach my rbd volumes.

Something is wrong with it. Can you open an issue to ceph and post here the issue, please?